# Sql query works normally, but fails when dynamic

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000, dynamic-sql

I have a query, which works when its run like this:

```
  declare @nvRecipients varchar(4000)
    ,@CustomerCode varchar(6)
    ,@start datetime
    ,@end datetime

 SELECT @CustomerCode = '10095'
       ,@start = '01/01/2011'
       ,@end = '02/01/2011'

  Select substring(PSD.DTSItemCode,1,4) As ItemCompanyCode , 
  convert(varchar(50),Cast(Sum(PSD.Quantity) as money),1) As TotalShipped 
  From  [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].AVANTI.dbo.PackingSlipHeader PSH 
  Inner Join  [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].AVANTI.dbo.PackingSlipsDetail PSD On PSH.PKSNumber = PSD.PKSNumber 
  Where Cast ( PKSDate As DateTime ) >= @start
    And Cast ( PKSDate As DateTime ) <= @end
    And PSD.Quantity > 0  
    And ( CompanyCode = @CustomerCode)
   Group By  substring(PSD.DTSItemCode,1,4) 
   Order By  substring(PSD.DTSItemCode,1,4)
```

But throws the error

> Syntax error converting datetime from
>   character string.

When ran like this within a stored procedure where @customercode, @start, and @end are supplied parameters:

```
       Set @nvQuery = ' Select substring(PSD.DTSItemCode,1,4) As ItemCompanyCode , '
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + ' convert(varchar(50),Cast(Sum(PSD.Quantity) as money),1) As TotalShipped ' 
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + ' From  [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].AVANTI.dbo.PackingSlipHeader PSH '
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + ' Inner Join  [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].AVANTI.dbo.PackingSlipsDetail PSD On PSH.PKSNumber = PSD.PKSNumber '
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + ' Where Cast ( PKSDate As DateTime ) >= ''' + @start + ''' '
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + '   And Cast ( PKSDate As DateTime ) <= ''' + @end + ''' '
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + '   And PSD.Quantity > 0 '  
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + '   And ( CompanyCode = ''' + @CustomerCode + ''') '
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + '  Group By  substring(PSD.DTSItemCode,1,4) '
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + '  Order By  substring(PSD.DTSItemCode,1,4) '
```

Can anyone see my error?  I can't seem to find it.  The data all checks out with ISDATE().

Comment: I haven't tried it but for starters, you explicitly cast to datetime in your query but implicit (read not) in your dynamicly created query

Comment: Yeah, that was a mistake (a variation I've tried it both ways).  I've edited the question back to the original way, casting in both places.

Comment: You have cast Quantity as Datetime. I doubt that whas what you intended.

Comment: If both really are the same as you say, better to copy past the *actual* snippets instead of manually editing them.

Comment: Sry, that is confusing.  I've just copied the original code into here. Although, the behavior was the same with and without the cast statements.  Weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they're dates, the you need to cast them to varchar to append to the query.

You cannot concatenate a datetime to a string w/o casting it first:

```
Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + '   And Cast( PKSDate As DateTime) <= ''' + CAST(@end AS VARCHAR(20)) + ''' '
```

---

```
  Set @nvQuery = ' Select substring(PSD.DTSItemCode,1,4) As ItemCompanyCode , '
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + ' convert(varchar(50),Cast(Sum(PSD.Quantity) as money),1) As TotalShipped ' 
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + ' From  [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].AVANTI.dbo.PackingSlipHeader PSH '
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + ' Inner Join  [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].AVANTI.dbo.PackingSlipsDetail PSD On PSH.PKSNumber = PSD.PKSNumber '
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + ' Where Cast ( PKSDate As DateTime ) >= ''' + CONVERT(varchar(20), @start, 101) + ''' '
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + '   And Cast ( PKSDate As DateTime ) <= ''' + CONVERT(varchar(20), @end, 101) + ''' '
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + '   And PSD.Quantity > 0 '  
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + '   And ( CompanyCode = ''' + @CustomerCode + ''') '
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + '  Group By  substring(PSD.DTSItemCode,1,4) '
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + '  Order By  substring(PSD.DTSItemCode,1,4) '
```

Comment: Well, if I'm casting the PKSDate to a datetime, and the parameter @end is already a datetime, aren't I comparing dates?

Comment: You attempting to concatenate a date to a string... will not work

Comment: You have to cast the datetime variables to varchars to concatenate them to the query string.

Comment: You got it!  I still don't quite understand.  Its already a datetime, why am I converting it to a varchar, then back to a datetime?  I'll mark this as the answer when I'm allowed in 23 minutes.

Comment: because you want to concatenate strings together, not strings to dates.  Similarly, if you want to add an integer, you have to cast it to a varchar so that you can append it to the query string.

Comment: So I'm wanting/expecting it to cast datetime to varchar implicitly?  And it doesn't do that for those types.  Hmm, ok got it now.

Comment: the compiler will implicitly convert, but you're not getting that far since you haven't concatenated all of your strings to execute it.  Just FYI, you should consider changing PKSDate to a datetime in your table.  A mistype will ruin your query - it won't be able to cast and you'll get an epic fail.

Comment: Wish I could.  I understand the kind of fail your referring to, but i"m limited to dealing with it like this.

Answer (score 2):

To save yourself a lot of trouble, you can use parameters with dynamic SQL as well, yes! - parameters, just like in your real query.

```
  Set @nvQuery = ' Select substring(PSD.DTSItemCode,1,4) As ItemCompanyCode , '
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + ' convert(varchar(50),Cast(Sum(PSD.Quantity) as money),1) As TotalShipped ' 
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + ' From  [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].AVANTI.dbo.PackingSlipHeader PSH '
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + ' Inner Join  [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].AVANTI.dbo.PackingSlipsDetail PSD On PSH.PKSNumber = PSD.PKSNumber '
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + ' Where Cast ( PKSDate As DateTime ) >= @start '
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + '   And Cast ( PKSDate As DateTime ) <= @end '
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + '   And PSD.Quantity > 0 '  
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + '   And ( CompanyCode = @CustomerCode) '
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + '  Group By  substring(PSD.DTSItemCode,1,4) '
  Set @nvQuery = @nvQuery + '  Order By  substring(PSD.DTSItemCode,1,4) '
```

Instead of running it via

```
EXEC (@nvQuery)
```

use the form

```
exec sp_executeSQL @nvQuery,
     N'@start datetime,@end datetime,@customerCode varchar(6)', --list of params
     @start, @end, @customerCode -- params, matching list
```

This gets around all sorts of string manipulation, cast/format issues. e.g.

```
declare @start datetime,@end datetime,@customerCode varchar(6)
select @start = getdate(), @end = getdate()+2, @customerCode = 'TEST'

set @nvQuery ... -- build the statement

exec sp_executeSQL @nvQuery,
     N'@start datetime,@end datetime,@customerCode varchar(6)', --list of params
     @start, @end, @customerCode -- params, matching list
```

Comment: Does this work in SQL Server 2000?  Also, where do I assign the values?

Comment: @MAW - yes it does work in 2000. And you assign the values as you normally would to any variable before calling a stored proc. Please see updated answer. It is a lot more robust and less prone to SQL injection

Comment: So the trick is that i have to declare the variables twice, once in the procedure en totale, then another time in the N' statement.  Ok, I see.

Comment: Now, I'm actually not executing this query directly, I'm passing it to xp_sendmail.  Still works?

Comment: Richard's method is the preferred way to do dynamic SQL.  With sp_executeSQL, SQL *could* cache the execution plan.  Where EXEC will get recompiled every time.  I was just answering the question about making your existing code work.

Comment: lol  Does that change things?  Although its still a great tip for other things.